# Angular: DatePipe.transform returning 0 for month

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I'm using DatePipe to format a date string of format '25-Oct-2017' to '2017-10-25'. Below is the snippet.

```
this.datePipe.transform('25-Oct-2017', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

It returns '2017-00-25'.

Comment: mm means minutes. Use MM. https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 1):

Please use proper representation symbols

```
 this.datePipe.transform('25-Oct-2017', 'y-MM-dd')
```

- y (2015)
- MM (10)
- dd (25)